# edit message doesnt work discordpy (nextcord)

Tags: python, if-statement

Im making this command where if i said =help fun, fun commands should show up and if i said =help economy, economy commands should show up too. But this code doesnt work any fixes?

```
    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx, arg1):
        if arg1 != "fun":
            return
        else:
            #Help fun
            embedFun = nextcord.Embed(
                title="Need help?",
                description="Fun: ",
                color=nextcord.Color.green())

            embedFun.set_thumbnail(url="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/money-icons/money-icon-29.png")

            embedFun.add_field(
                name="`=howsimp`",
                value="Shows how simp you or your friends are.",
                inline=False
            )
            embedFun.add_field(
                name="`=help economy`",
                value="Shows you the economy category commands.",
                inline=False
            )   
            funHelp = await ctx.reply(embed=embedFun)

        if arg1 != "economy":
            return
        else:
           #Help economy
            embedEconomy = nextcord.Embed(
                title="Need help?",
                description="Economy: ",
                color=nextcord.Color.green())

            embedEconomy.set_thumbnail(url="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/money-icons/money-icon-29.png")

            embedEconomy.add_field(
                name="`=balance`",
                value="Shows how simp you or your friends are.",
                inline=False
            )
            embedEconomy.add_field(
                name="`=help economy`",
                value="Shows you the economy category commands.",
                inline=False
            )   
            await funHelp.edit(embed=embedEconomy)
```

### btw im using discord.py's fork "nextcord"

---

Answer (score 1):

1. you should not use this weird "if != else" structure. Use elif or Structural Pattern Matching.
2. funHelp is not a global variable therefore .edit is called to a NoneType
3. to accomplish what you are trying try [.history](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#nextcord.TextChannel.history) or [buttons](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=button#nextcord.Button)

Answer (score 0):

before filling out the content for if-else clauses, it is better to write conditional blocks first to see logic problems. your code have this beginner's issue. currently, for any case other than `fun`, it immediately exits empty and will return a result only for `=help fun`.

```
    if arg1 != "fun":
        return
    else:
        #Help fun
    if arg1 != "economy":
        return
    else:
       #Help economy
```

the following is the correct way. you can also use if-elif-else blocks

```
    if arg1 == "fun":
       #Help fun
    if arg1 == "economy":
       #Help economy
    return
```

or

```
    if arg1 == "fun":
       #Help fun
    elif arg1 == "economy":
       #Help economy
    else:
       return
```

I haven't checked your code for frameworks problems. if this does not fix your problem, let me know for another look.